# Медиаплеер не воспроизводит звук

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Перед таймером в коде диалоговое окно, onClick в приведённом фрагменте кода из одной из кнопок диалога. После таймера идёт Toast, который работает нормально, а вот плеер не хочет воспроизводить звук.

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialogfeed.dismiss();
                    CountDownTimerfeed = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millis) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                         final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.melodyfeed);
                         mp.start();
                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разве у объекта типа `CountDownTimer` не надо вызывать `start`?

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: спасибо огромное, не досмотрел))